My Profile error in Contacts App on Galaxy A52s 5G
I have a Samsung Galaxy A52s 5G. The wrong contact was accidentally selected when setting the "My profile" section in setting up the phone. This is in the Contacts app, and not the Settings.
I can't find a way to correct this.
Help! How can I fix it?

Based on my testing, the info from Contacts is linked with the one from the Settings/Samsung account. Have you tried editing either one and seeing whether they sync?

Thanks Andrew, The Samsung account is correct, and it's not syncing with the contacts app. Most puzzling... Thanks for the idea. Kevin
